# Open a PPT from an URL (sharepoint) in VBS

Tags: vba, sharepoint, vbscript, office365

imagine a script to open a ppt file and export all slides.
This script does exactly this:
https://github.com/docToolchain/docToolchain/blob/master/scripts/exportPPT.vbs#L44

I would now like to extend it to open a ppt from an office365 share-link and export the slides.
But it seems that the `Presentations.Open()` method does not like URLs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentations.open

...and the `Presentation.FollowHyperlink()` opens the presentation, but I don't get a handle to access it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.followhyperlink

any further idea what I could try?

Comment: `Presentations.Open()` works OK with URL's but you need the correct format of link to get it to work.  If you use the SharePoint "copy link" function then it seems to give you a "web view" link not a "download" link.

Comment: that is a good hint. Do you know how I can turn a "web view" link into a "download" one?

Comment: It may vary according to your setup, but for me a copied link looks like `https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/:p:/r/sites/Blah/TestLibrary/Presentation.pptx?d=56fabcc31e450arr58513f3b80886427d&csf=1&web=1&e=nQflGa`  Removing the `:p:/r/` from the URL is enough to be able to open the presentation in PPT

Comment: wow. I would have never guessed this. I tried to change the web parameter...
can you copy and paste your comments as answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer? Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Presentations.Open()` works OK with URL's but you need the correct format of link to get it to work. If you use the SharePoint "copy link" function then it seems to give you a "web view" link not a "download" link.

It may vary according to your setup, but for me a copied link looks like:

`https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/:p:/r/sites/Blah/TestLibrary/Presentation.pptx?d=56fabcc31e450arr58513f3b80886427d&csf=1&web=1&e=nQflGa`

Removing the `:p:/r/` from the URL is enough to be able to open the presentation in PPT