# Error when trying to download file from SharePoint URL and open it

Tags: excel, vba, url, download

At work, I'm writing a macro. The summary of the macro's function is as follows:

1. User inputs SharePoint Link
2. Macro downloads file from link
3. Macro opens file
4. Macro copies data from downloaded file, pastes into the original file and sets up formulas, formatting, etc in the original file

The issue lies in step 2. Once the macro tries to open the downloaded file, I get the following error:

"Excel cannot open the file 'temp.xlsx' because the file format or extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and the file extension matches the format of the file."

When I end the macro and try to open up the file manually, I get the same error, so the issue lies with the file itself.

I have tried saving the file in different formats. Excel throws the same error when I download as a .xlsm. When downloaded as a .xls, the file turns up blank. If downloaded as a .txt, the text is just info of the file I downloaded, not the data.

If someone has an alternative way to get data from a Sharepoint file instead of a fix to the error, that would be great as well!

Below is steps 1-3 of my code:

````
'Input box + declarations
    Dim myValue As String
    myValue = InputBox("Enter Sharepoint Link")
    
'Declarations
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strURL As String
    strURL = myValue
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim returnValue As Long
'userName is entered in a cell because different users may be running the macro, but we do not want to have to prompt the user to enter their username every time
    Dim userName As String
    userName = Sheets("Reference").Range("B4").Text
    Dim Path As String
    Dim R As Range
    Dim R2 As Range

'Set dynamic path and save
    strSavePath = "C:\Users\" & userName & "\OneDrive - Ingredion\Desktop\temp.xlsx"
    returnValue = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strSavePath, 0, 0)

'open workbook and copy cells
    Workbooks.Open strSavePath```
````

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472698/open-a-ppt-from-an-url-sharepoint-in-vbs/68480065#68480065  SharePoint links have a tendency not be be the "download" path but instead are specific to viewing the file within SharePoint...

Comment: See also: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47729/link-to-download-a-copy-from-a-document-library